# Monero Ring CT sj calculation

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency, schnorr-signature

For a university project, I am currently implementing the RingCT Ring signatures as  used in Monero (before the introduction of Bulletproofs) as laid out in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf).
To close the ring we calculate the last $s$ like this: (where $\alpha$ is the random value initially chosen and $l$ is the order of the elliptic curve group)
$$s_j = α − c_j· x_j \bmod l $$

So as I understand the modulo in this case only applies to the $$c_j· x_j$$ otherwise we might get an out of range scalar, but then if this value is bigger then $\alpha$ it could happen that the $s$ is negative? Do I need another modulos here or do I understand something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

All of the arithmetic is done modulo $l$ here.  The notation is slightly confusing—I would have written it as: $$s_j \equiv \alpha - c_j\cdot x_j \pmod l.$$  It may not actually matter whether the integer representative you choose for the scalar is positive or negative; there are many equivalent choices of scalar that will yield the same result when you multiply a curve point by them.  (But the specific algorithm you use to compute scalar multiplication may impose constraints on the integer, like being positive and below a certain size.)

Comment: I see thanks. Yes, I already thought so but then you would have to make sure that the other s values, calculated randomly can be negative too, otherwise, you might be giving away for which key you signed.